# Is this grammar left factored?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

Consider the following grammar

```
S --> A|B  
A --> aa   
B --> ab
```

Is this grammar left factored?

I feel this grammar is not left factored, since the choices between the two productions of `S` is not clear we could rewrite the productions to defer this decision until enough of the input has been seen that we can make right choice.

Am I missing something or this is not left factored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few reasons why a grammar isn't LL(1). In this case, you have a **FIRST/FIRST conflict** between `S -> A` and `S -> B`: because `FIRST(A)` and `FIRST(B)` overlap, there are cases where you don't know which production to pick.

The techniques that are commonly *taught* to resolve these conflicts are left factoring and left recursion removal, but this grammar is already left-factored (for each non-terminal, each productions has a distinct prefix) and it's free of any left recursion.

There is another technique you can use, however: **substitution**. In your case, you could remove the rule `A -> aa` by replacing `S -> A` with `S -> aa`.

---

To solve the conflict in your grammar, one would first have to substitute `A` and `B` in `S`:

```
S -> aa | ab
```

Now we still have a FIRST/FIRST conflict between the two productions for `S`, but this time, we can resolve it through left factoring:

```
S -> a T
T -> a | b
```

The grammar is now free of LL(1) conflicts.

---

*(Unfortunately, I'm not well-versed enough in parser construction to know of a mechanical way to determine when and where substitution should be applied. Nevertheless, it's a valid technique.)*

Comment: Thank you Rhymoid.
but how this grammar is ambiguous? It can derive only two strings namely 'aa' and 'ab', & both of them cab be uniquely derived.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I don't know what I was thinking. It's perhaps not ambiguous, but I wouldn't call it "not left-factored" either. I'll look further into it and come back when I have a better answer.

Comment: @AnuragPandey I've updated my answer. Your grammar wasn't ambiguous. However, it *is* left-factored. The problem is more accurately described as a FIRST/FIRST conflict between the production rules `S -> A` and `S -> B`.

Comment: Ohh, I was unaware about the concept of FIRST/FIRST conflict.Thank you @Rhymoid

Comment: I have one more doubt, if any unambiguous left factored context free grammar is free from FIRST/FIRST, & FIRST/FOLLOW conflicts & left recursion then, can we guarantee that it must be an LL(1) grammar?

Comment: @AnuragPandey [This answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/6774/21412) on the CS StackExchange site says that is the case, and demonstrates it with a better example. A grammar is LL(1) if and only if you can build an an LL(1) parsing table, which is possible exactly when there are no LL(1) conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the link. :)